# Why accept4() is slow with Apache?

Tags: apache-http-server, strace

I am running a website on Apache2 and I noticed that the first bit is always slow to come.

I tried to diagnose the problem with `strace` and found that `accept4()` is slow on each request.
Below the trace. What could be the cause of that ?

```
0.000120 accept4(4, {sa_family=AF_INET6, sin6_port=htons(36300), inet_pton(AF_INET6, "::ffff:127.0.0.1", &sin6_addr), sin6_flowinfo=0, sin6_scope_id=0}, [28], SOCK_CLOEXEC) = 13
2.320681 getsockname(13, {sa_family=AF_INET6, sin6_port=htons(8090), inet_pton(AF_INET6, "::ffff:127.0.0.1", &sin6_addr), sin6_flowinfo=0, sin6_scope_id=0}, [28]) = 0
0.000148 fcntl(13, F_GETFL)        = 0x2 (flags O_RDWR)
0.000063 fcntl(13, F_SETFL, O_RDWR|O_NONBLOCK) = 0
```

Comment: Do the numbers refer to the duration of this syscall, or to offset since previous syscall?

Comment: They refer to the time in second since previous call. For instance, it took 2.320681 to execute accept4()

Comment: Ah, but "time since previous call" doesn't mean the previous syscall took the whole time -- it also includes all userspace code that ran _between_ accept4() and getsockname().

Comment: What could be the cause of this delay ? Or how to debug it ?